# How do I want the output to be in two decimal places?

Tags: javascript

I am practicing XHTML with JavaScript. I want the cost to be in two decimal places, just like how we calculate money in real life. How would I do that? This is my code in the JavaScript file:

```
function computeCost() {
    var french = document.getElementById("french").value;
    var hazlenut = document.getElementById("hazlenut").value;
    var colombian = document.getElementById("colombian").value;
    var regular = document.getElementById("regular").value;

//Compute the cost
    document.getElementById("cost").value =
    totatCost = french * 3.49 + hazlenut * 3.95 + colombian * 4.59 
            + regular * 1.99;
} // end computeCost
```

Comment: XHTML is a dead spec, you should be concentrating your efforts on HTML5

Comment: Please note the first highly voted comment on the linked question regarding not actually using float for currency in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [toFixed()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tofixed.asp), it will also round your number.

```
var num = 5.56789;
var n = num.toFixed(2);  // n = 5.57
```